# pushwoosh setTags "Device not found" error

Tags: pushwoosh

setTags method always
returns a 201 error code, the device is not found. even though I use
the same device id in the createMessage method and it works fine. Are
those different? I mean aren't "devices" and "hwid" both refer to the
same thing ? devices are a list of hwids, right?

Answer (score 1):

from PushWoosh Support

> Hello,  Thank you for contacting us!  deviceId and hwid are two
>   different things. If you check the registerDevice method, there is a
>   "push_token" or "deviceID", which is being sent by APNS/GCM. It is
>   unique for each app on each device, even though with iOS sometimes it
>   is similar for several different apps on one device.  hwid is the
>   hardware ID that we set with our SDK. It is being sent in setTag
>   method.  Please note that you do not have to add anything manually.
>   The setTag method is a method that our SDK calls, so it takes the same
>   hwid which is used in registerDevice.  Please let me know if I may be
>   of any further help!  Kind regards, Nastya Lagunova Pushwoosh Team